# Challenging SQL query to perform matrix multiplication

Tags: mysql, join, currency

I have the following two tables:

```
sales
- id
- sales_price
- currency
- date

exchange
- currency
- conversion_to_usd
- date
```

In the sales table I may have any number of currencies, for example `aud`, `chf`, `nzd`, etc...

I need to get the total sales converted to USD. The following would be a manual example:

```
sales
(10.20, 'NZD', '2012-10-01')
(4.15,  'AUD', '2012-09-01')
...

exchange
('AUD', 1.02, '2012-08-01')
('AUD', 1.03, '2012-09-01')
('NZD', 0.89, '2012-10-01)

  10.20 (cost NZD) * 0.89 (NZD conversion) 
+ 4.15 (cost AUD) * 1.03 (AUD conversion)
= 13.3525
```

I'm able to do it for an individual currency, but am having a hard time generalizing the  query to be able to get all sums for a given date.

```
SELECT SUM(sales_price) * conversion_to_usd FROM sales
    INNER JOIN exchange
    using (currency, date) 
    WHERE currency = "AUD" and date = "2012-09-01"
```

Given a date, how would I do this combined query?

I would like to get the result to be in the following form:

```
sales_in_usd    currency       date
100             AUD            2012-01-01
150             CAD            2012-01-01
40              DKK            2012-01-01
36              JPY            2012-01-01
etc...
```

Note that I am looking for the **general** query, as there will be in excess of 30 currencies.

Comment: This question is tagged with three different RDBMS; which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `GROUP BY` command?

```
SELECT SUM(sales_price) * conversion_to_usd AS 'Sales in US$', 
    currency AS 'Currency', 
    date AS 'Date' FROM sales
INNER JOIN exchange
    USING (currency, date) 
WHERE date = "2012-09-01"
GROUP BY currency;
```